# Difficulty in changing color of text when hover over it

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the color of the text to white when hover over it, but I am unable to do so.

Here is my code that I tried . How can I make sure that color of the text changes to white when hover over it and also text size changes when hover over it?

This is the code that I tried

```css
h1::before,
h1::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
  transition: width .3s ease;
}

h1:hover::before,
h1:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

h1::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

h1::after {
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
 
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="text-wrapper">


  <h1 id='text'>
    Days are gone </h1>


</div> 
</body>
```

Comment: There is no code.Please post the code

Comment: Please check the code

Comment: Your h1:hover color is the same as not hovered. You need to change it to #fff

Comment: You have the same color for normal and hover.

Comment: Your `h1:hover {...}` is set to the same colour as your normal `<h1>` (#6849e3). Change this to #fff.

Comment: Yes I have the same color, sorry the color of the lines should be blue not white

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing text color on hover using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342262/changing-text-color-on-hover-using-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `:hover`.`#text:hover{color:red}`

```css
body {
  Background: #7a86cb;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #6849e3;
  font-family: Merriweather;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

h1:hover {
   color: #6849e3;
   
 }

h1::before,
h1::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  background: blue;
  transition: width .3s ease;
}

h1:hover::before,
h1:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

h1::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

h1::after {
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
 
}
#text:hover{
color:red
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="text-wrapper">


  <h1 id='text'>
    INTERNET </h1>


</div> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have done everything perfectly except, you just need to change

**this**

```
h1:hover {
   color: #6849e3;
 }
```

**to**

```
h1:hover {
   color: white;
 }
```